# How to fix syntax/text highlighting in ReST?

Tags: eclipse, restructuredtext

I have just installed [ReST 1.0.5](http://resteditor.sourceforge.net/) On Eclipse Mars. The text is hardly readable:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found out where to fix the highlighting:

*Window* > *Preferences* > *General* > *Appearance* > *Colours and Fonts* > *ReST Editor*

Then it is a matter of modifying each of the colours in that category:

[image]